# How to access vue component data from socket.io listener function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, socket.io

I have this code on my server,

```js
socket.on('join-room', (roomId, passcode, nickname) => {
        room = rooms.find((e) => e.id == roomId)

        if (!room) {
            socket.emit('join-room-error', 'Room not found!',)
            return
        }
        if (room.users.has(nickname)) {
            socket.emit('join-room-error', 'Nickname has been used!',)
            return
        }
        if (!room.passcode) {
            JoinRoomWithNickname(room, nickname)
            return
        }
        if (room.passcode != passcode) {
            socket.emit('join-room-error', 'Wrong passcode!')
            return
        }

        JoinRoomWithNickname(room, nickname)
    })
```

and I want to listen to the error from socket.io. So in the **created** function I add some listener but it's seem in the listener function I can't access the vue component data

```js
    created() {
        this.$socket.removeAllListeners()

        this.$socket.on('join-room-success', function() {
            store.state.roomId = this.id
            router.push('/room')
        })
        this.$socket.on('join-room-error', function(err) {
          this.errorLog = err
          // I can't access this.errorLog from there
        })
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            code: '',
            nickname: '',
            wasWrongPasscode: false,
            isEnteringPasscode: true,
            errorLog: null
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use arrow functions when you want to pass the global context (this) to the function being invoked.

```
this.$socket.on('join-room-error', (err) => {
          this.errorLog = err
        })
```

Comment: I'm just trying it after watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOlr79NaAtQ&ab_channel=Fireship) then it just works =)). But anyway, thank you <3